# Adapting javascript function to open link in new tab

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click

Is there a way of adapting the following javascript to either open the link below in a new browser tab or window?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("yellow")[0].click();
```

Link on page looks like this: `<a class="yellow">Buy</a>`

The javascript needs to be entered in a plugin. I can't alter the code on the page itself.

Comment: what link? what function?

Comment: @jony89 sorry - I have clarified the question now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

JS:

```
url = document.getElementById("yellow").getAttribute("href");
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

Comment: This would be altering the code on the page itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a plug in script to achieve this, you'll want to include something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("yellow")[0];

el.onclick = function () {
    newTab(this.href);
};

function newTab(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

This will add onclick listener to the element in question, and use it's `href` property to open that url in a new tab/window (depending on browser settings).

Pop-up blocker add-ons will probably disallow this though...